# how to slicing List value in python dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a question somthing about dataframe in python.

```
first, this is data frame
index       id                           keyword
0         @aaa_24 @bbb_2     ["@max", "@travel", ... ,"@food"]
1         @aa_1  @c_5        ["@animal", "@weather", ... ,"@coco"]
2         @ab_7  @ba_3                     ...
3         @ccc_1                           ...
...       ...                              ...

and i want to convert like this
index      id           keyword
0       @aaa @bbb     unique.keyword()  --> (count value)    
1       @aa  @c       unique.keyword()  --> (count value) 
2       @ab  @ba      unique.keyword()  --> (count value)
3       @ccc          unique.keyword()  --> (count value)
...        ...
```

please, check this problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is the objective here. From what I understand, you want to get the frequencies of keywords in the keywords column:

```
def f(x):
    dic = {}
    ans = []
    for val in x:
        if val not in dic:
            dic[val]=0
        dic[val]+=1
    for key in dic.keys():
        ans.append((key,dic[key]))
    return ans
df['new_keyword'] = df['keywords'].apply(f)
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your problem

Comment: Thanks your reply. I'm not asking for a way to express a dictionary. I mean is to find the string parsing and unique value. Is there a good way to reduce time complexity? Thank you so much!

Comment: The time complexity can not be better than linear if you use hashing.